# Merge sort in C++ with iterators

Tags: c++, mergesort

I implemented merge sort with C++ and would like to get some feedback.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<typename It>
std::vector<typename It::value_type> merge(const It begin, const It mid, const It end)
{
    std::vector<typename It::value_type> v;
    It it_l{ begin }, it_r{ mid };
    const It it_mid{ mid }, it_end{ end };
    
    while (it_l != it_mid && it_r != it_end)
    {
        v.push_back((*it_l <= *it_r) ? *it_l++ : *it_r++);
    }   

    v.insert(v.end(), it_l, it_mid);    
    v.insert(v.end(), it_r, it_end);

    return std::move(v);
}

template<typename It>
void merge_sort(It begin, It end)
{
    auto size = std::distance(begin, end);
    if (size < 2)
        return;
    
    auto mid = std::next(begin, size / 2);
    merge_sort(begin, mid);
    merge_sort(mid, end);

    auto &&v = merge(begin, mid, end);
    std::move(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), begin);
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<int> v{ 8, 4, 1, 9, 16, 3 };
merge_sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Is there anything I should avoid? Any mistakes in the algorithm or implementation? It should work with other containers (e.g. `std::list`) as well.

Answer (score 6):

Very nice overall.
Don't see anything technically wrong.

I agree with @ratchet freak that your variable naming (and declaring multiple objects in one line) is a not great. I would prefer better names and one variable per line.

Things I would change for efficiency:

```
// You know how big this vector is going to get.
std::vector<typename It::value_type> v;

// So reserve the appropriate space:
v.reserve(std::distance(begin, end));
```

Also this is not what you want:

```
return std::move(v);

// jsut return the object
return v;
```

Otherwise you will screw up RVO done by the compiler and it will generate a copy rather than a move.

At the call site the value returned by a function is already an rvalue reference. So adding the move here does not change anything (it will still be moved).

But this is not going to move the values:

```
buffer.push_back((*left <= *right) ? *left++ : *right++);
```

Here you are only getting lvalues passed to `push_back` so you are copying the underlying elements. Why not try and get a move out of it?

```
buffer.push_back(std::move((*left <= *right) ? *left++ : *right++));
```

Comment: Actually, `return std::move(loval_variable)` is a pessimization, as it makes RVO impossible.

Answer (score 4):

You may wish to allow the user to select his own Compare function instead of forcing `operator<`, and use `std::less` as default.

The naming in `merge()` is not great:

```
std::vector<typename It::value_type> buffer;

It left(begin);
It right(mid);
const It &left_end = mid; //by ref -> no copy
const It &right_end = end;

while (left != left_end && right != right_end)
{
    buffer.push_back((*left <= *right) ? *left++ : *right++);
}   

buffer.insert(v.end(), left, left_end);    
buffer.insert(v.end(), right, right_end);
```

The temporary buffer is repeatedly allocated and freed. Instead you can preallocate a buffer and pass it through as parameter.

Then during the merge you *copy* the values with `push_back()`; instead you can *move* from the selected iterator:

```
    buffer.push_back((*left <= *right) ? std::move(*left++) : std::move(*right++));
```

Comment: not really because that doesn't increment the iterator `*left++` evaluates to `*(left++)` your solution inverts the priority nesting and increments the actual element

Answer (score 2):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this line is misleading:

```
std::move(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), begin);
```

`std::move` is called with `const` iterators, and therefore the program wouldn't benefit from move semantics: copy constructor will be called.

I think better would be to just use:

```
std::move(v.begin(), v.end(), begin);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function takes `const It` because it does not change the values of the variables named by the parameters; but it neglects to make the iterator refer to a `const` object, when the input is not modified by the function.

If the template auto-deduces a type which is a `const_iterator` of some kind, you are fine.  But if you call it with something like `v.begin(), v.end()` where `v` was not `const` already, then you'll carry forward the non-const-ness of the iterators.

The top-level function that you actually call should declare local variables of the corresponding `const_iterator` and assign the parameters to those; basically, get the `const` on there as soon as possible without making it more complicated to write the template.